# Cutting small tiles accurately and safely

Tags: tile

I am re-tiling my fireplace with a mixture of tile sizes. The smallest tile that needs cut is a triangle of dimension 35x35x50mm - all tiles are 10mm thick. I don't think it will be possible to cut such a tile in half manually (would be preferable)? I have an electric tile cutter - how should i feed such a small tile into the cutting disc in a stable linear manner without cutting my fingers off...?

Comment: What sort of saw do you have?

Comment: Dremel-type tool with water, clamp, and safety glasses

Comment: How many of these small tiles do you need to cut?

Answer (score 1):

Not to discount the need for safety, but tile blades are relatively low-risk. I'd use heavy, well-fitting leather gloves to virtually eliminate the chance of injury.

Grasp the tile with both hands, elbows spread. By keeping your arms to the sides you prevent slips that would result in your fingers finding the blade. Press the tile firmly to the table or slide and move slowly past the blade. It's imperative that a firm grip is maintained and that the tile's orientation remains steady.

You could also clamp the tile, using a rubber pad, and cut with an angle grinder and diamond wheel.